# Entity Code First Custom Data Type

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

2 Questions regarding custom data-types in Entity Framework and performing things automatically...

1. I have a class that is able to provide a string representation of itself and construct itself from a string.  Is there anyway to include this class as a property of a E-CF class and have it create a string underneath?  e.g:

   ```
   public class MySpecialClass
   {
       public MySpecialClass(string _data)
       {
       } // eo ctor


       public string ToString()
       {
       } // eo ToString
   } // eo MySpecialClass


   public class EntityObject
   {
       public MySpecialClass Special {get; set; }
   } // eo class EntityObject
   ```

   That would be really useful!
2. I have a whole bunch of classes that have things such as `CreatedBy`, `ModifiedBy`, `ModifiedDate` etceteras.  Is there an easy way to automatically set these when an object is first created, or whenever it is modified at a later point?  Ideally I'd like an event I could hook in to to implement this kind of behavior, as some of my objects actually require a write to a "history" table if certain fields change.  Actually, is there any way to do that too?  To know if a certain field was modified during an update?

Comment: Next time you should ask two separate questions because they are not related - you will more probably receive good answer for each of them.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, in hindsight you're absolutely right.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your entity you must define property as string. EF is not able to work with custom classes. Each generated entity class is defined as partial so you can define additional property in partial class which will work with instance of your type:

```
// EF generated part
public partial class EntityObject
{
  protected string SpecialString { get; set; }
}

// Your part
public partial class EntityObject
{
  public MySpecialClass Special
  {
    get
    {
      return MySpecialClass.Deserialize(SpecialString);
    }
    set
    {
      SpecialString = MySpecialClass.Serialize(value);
    }
  }
}
```

You will not be able to use Special property in Linq-To-Entities queries.

> **Edit:**
>
> I didn't notice that you are using
>   code-first. In such case you don't use
>   partial classes for entities and you
>   can use same approach in single entity
>   where MySpecialClass will be marked with
>   `NotMappedAttribute`.

For your second question - it is usually responsibility of data access layer (currently very popular repository pattern). The only build-in events available in EF are

- `ObjectCotnext.ObjectMaterialized` - fired when data are loaded from DB and instance of object is created
- `ObjectContext.SavingChanges` - fired before EF executes changes in DB

You can add some custom events if you override `SaveChanges` method.